# Do not see BizTalk projects in VS 2010 Ultimate

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate installed on my local machine. I used it for c# development for quite some time.

Now I have a project for BizTalk development. When I click New Project I do not see the BizTalk project option.

What do I need to do to get BizTalk projects on my Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to download a version of BizTalk from Microsoft and install at least the developer tools and SDK.  But usually you will want to do a complete install unless you already have a BizTalk Server you can deploy to for development purposes.
See this thread [What do you need to develop in BizTalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480905/what-do-you-need-to-develop-in-biztalk)

Answer (score 0):

Step1:

Launch BizTalk Setup>Modify>Unselect 'Developer tools SDK'>Complete the installation.

Step 2:

Launch BizTalk Setup>Modify>Select 'Developer tools SDK'>Complete the installation.

After you have performed Step1 and Step 2, or you may have not Installed Developer Tools SDK then perform only Step 2.

Start>>Visual Studio 2010 >> Biztalk >> Biztalk Empty Project>> If you now see it then you can assume that your Developer Tools have been successfully installed.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25177.biztalk-server-start-developing-a-simple-biztalk-application-for-biztalk-beginners.aspx